# Change RecyclerView Row When Observe User

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-mvvm

I am building a chat app with Firebase and MVVM.

I built a feature to show if the user is online or offline. I observe the app lifeCycle and updating the value in the user real time database under the key: `"status"`.

So I have a recyclerview that displays all the user's recent chats, and I am observing each user data.
When the user logout or exit the app the "status" is updated .
**The goal is to update the recyclerView row and change the online icon to the offline icon.**

Right now I am doing it through the adapter class.

First I set the list like below:

```
fun setUserList(newList: List<LinkedHashMap<String, Any?>>?, context: Context) {

    if (this::theUserList.isInitialized) {
     (theUserList as ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, Any?>>).clear()
    }

    if(!::lifecycleOwner.isInitialized){
        lifecycleOwner = context as LifecycleOwner
    }

    if (newList != null) {

        // Remove Duplicates Users
        val hs = LinkedHashSet<LinkedHashMap<String, Any?>>()
        hs.addAll(newList)
        (newList as ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, Any?>>)
        newList.clear()
        newList.addAll(hs)


        val sortedList = newList.sortedByDescending { it["Messages"].toString().toInt() }

        theUserList = sortedList
        notifyDataSetChanged()

        if (theUserList != null) {

            for (user in theUserList.indices){


                val userPosition : Int = user
                val userHashMap : HashMap<String, Any?> = theUserList[userPosition]
                val userDetails: User = userHashMap["Sender"] as User

                    mainRepository.checkUserStatus(userDetails.uid).observe(lifecycleOwner){

                        updateUserStatus(userPosition,it)

                    }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Now every time the user value is changing, I am using `updateUserStatus(userPosition,it)`:

```
private fun updateUserStatus(userPosition: Int, userHashMap: HashMap<String, Any>) {

        val userUID = userHashMap["userUID"] as String
        val userStatus = userHashMap["status"] as String
        val user : User = theUserList[userPosition]["Sender"] as User

        Log.e("HashMap","UID - $userUID")

        if (userStatus == "Online") {
            Log.e("HashMap","Online")
            itemBinding.lastChatsImageOffline.visibility = View.GONE
            itemBinding.lastChatsImageOnline.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            itemBinding.lastChatsUsersUserName.text = "Online"
            notifyItemChanged(userPosition)
        }else{
            Log.e("HashMap","Offline")
            itemBinding.lastChatsImageOffline.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            itemBinding.lastChatsImageOnline.visibility = View.GONE

            itemBinding.lastChatsUsersUserName.text = "Offline"
            notifyItemChanged(userPosition)
        }

    }
```

**The problem is that I don't get the right user position and the visibility of the images is not changing,only the textView change.**

If you have any other suggestions or criticism I really like to know how can I get better.

This is the full RecyclerViewAdapter code:
https://pastebin.com/nDbU3VeW

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

I have app same
Take My code is better
first There is library for firebase called firebaseUI [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-android)

use FirebaseUI Firestore
then eacth collecation has usersInfo such as name ,uid,phone,and status if online or not
And call method collection.EventListener to update every changed on collection

Comment: I want it to done like it should be, without any library help